# Multi-line title is not working when we export to PNG using CanVG - Highcharts

Tags: html, css, arrays, highcharts

I'm working on a creating a Highchart example, and I want to export the chart into PNG format. When downloading the PNG image, it displays differently than it does on the chart.

I have tried various approaches to add the title lines, but none of them are working for me.

Below see different attempts for adding the title lines

```
> 1. "text":"<p>Header Line Text</p><p>Line 2</p>Line 3"
> 2. "text":"<span style="display:block">Header Line Text</span><span style="display:block">Next Line</span>Line 3"
> 3. "text":"Header Line Text<br>Line 2<br>Line 3"
```

My example code is in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deepakpookkote/7jgc1nyq/5/

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you need such a result? - https://ibb.co/nn05BRn

Comment: @s.kuznetsov: yes, this is the result I'm expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove parameter `"useHTML":true` (or set `"useHTML":false`) from `"title":{}`. Also, remove the `<p>` tags, resulting in this format using the `<br>` tag:

```
"text": "Header Line Text<br>Line 2<br>Line 3"
```

Full:

```
"title":{
      "style":{
         "fontFamily":[
            "Arial Narrow"
         ],
         "fontSize":"12pt",
         "margin-left":"100px",
         "wordWrap":"break-word",
         "text-align":"center"
      },
      "align":"center",
      "text":"Header Line Text<br>Line 2<br>Line 3",
      "margin":10
   }
```

On output at DOM, each line (*Header Line Text, Line 2, Line 3*) will be wrapped in a `<tspan>` tag.

Also, the specified **styles** in the parameters are applied to the parent `<text>` tag.

Comment: Hi @s-kuznetsov,
Here my expectation is different, I wanted to have a title with multiple lines, like in the JSFiddle link i have shared, I was knowing about the sub-title scenario

As per my requirement I cannot use sub-title, :( 
Thanks for help :)

Comment: @DeepakPookkote, hi :)

Comment: @DeepakPookkote, I apologize for the long answer. Was busy. I have updated my answer. Check, pls.